# WebAPI HTTP request not completing until queued work kicks off on background task

Tags: c#, async-await, background-process

In my .Net 6 WebPI service, I am queueing work to a background task queue, very closely based on the example here, but I could post parts of my implementation if that would help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks

I am running into unexpected behavior where control is not returned to the caller, even after the `return Ok(..)` completes in the controller. Instead the request only completes after the `await Task.Delay(1000);` line is reached on the queued work item. The request returns to the client as soon as this line is reached, and does not need to wait for the `Delay` to finish.

I'm guessing this is because of the `await` either starting a new async context, or someone un-sticking the async context of the original request. My intention is for the request to complete immediately after queuing the work item.

Any insight into what is happening here would be greatly appreciated.

Controller:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
        {
            var resultMessage = await _testQueue.DoIt();

            return Ok(new { Message = resultMessage });
        }
```

Queueing Work:

```
        public TestAdapter(ITaskQueue taskQueue)
        {
            _taskQueue = taskQueue;
        }

        public async Task<string> DoIt()
        {
            await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async (_cancellationToken) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                var y = 12;
            });

            return "cool";
        }
```

IoC:

```
            services.AddHostedService<QueueHostedService>();
            services.AddSingleton<ITTaskQueue>(ctx =>
            {
                return new TaskQueue(MaxQueueCount);
            });
```

TaskQueue:

```
        private readonly Channel<BackgroundTaskContext> _queue;

        public TaskQueue(int capacity)
        {
            var options = new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
            {
                FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait
            };
            _queue = Channel.CreateBounded<BackgroundTaskContext>(options);
        }

        public async ValueTask QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(
            Func<CancellationToken, ValueTask> workItem)
        {
            if (workItem == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
            }

            await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync(new BackgroundTaskContext(workItem, ...));
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what you're seeing? The `await Task.Delay` will happen pretty much immediately, and can happen before the response is returned. Are you sure it *has* to happen before the response is returned?

Comment: Hello, yes fairly certain but I see what you mean.  I'll try modifying the example to better demonstrate what I'm seeing.

Comment: What is `ITaskQueue` ? What does `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync` return? If it returns the task returned by the delegate, `await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync` is essentially waiting for `Task.Delay` to complete

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, I edited the code to show what these are doing. I think my issue might be user error with the debugger though. I think the debugger is switching to the background task thread and hitting breakpoints there before the response fully returns (middleware etc) giving the appearance that control was never returned to the client. I'll test that today to be sure but if that is the case will post an update to close this out.

Comment: You created a bounded channel. Is it full perhaps? What's the capacity? `await _queue.Writer.WriteAsync` will block if the channel is already full and the default `FullMode` is used. This is expected. Have you tried creating an unbounded channel? If the channel gets full it means the worker isn't fast enough to process the requests. Right now, you're posting just `Task.Delay(1000)` so if you post every 1 second or faster, the worker will always be busy and the queue will grow

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect here. I'm assuming you want the async method to return the cool in the api response. That's fine but because your also awaiting the async call with in DoIt(), then it pauses until QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync finishes. You could remove the await and it will run and return as you expect.

I can't say that I'm a big fan of that design as you lose contact with it with exception of the cancellation token. Another thought would be to Send that work off to a console job or function app using message bus or even another http call.

Additional Notes:

Async can be complicated to explain because in reality, it wraps up code and executes on a thread of it's choosing. The await simulates the synchronous behavior.

await Task.Delay(1000); // Runs on it's own thread but still halts code execution for 1 second.

await _taskQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync(async (_cancellationToken) // Waits for control to be returned from the code inside.

var resultMessage = await _testQueue.DoIt(); // Always waits for the code inside to complete.

If your wanting something to run without pausing code execution, you can either remove the await or add a Task.Run(() => { }); pattern. Is it a good idea is a whole other question. It also matters whether you need information back from the async method. If you don't await it then you'll get null back as it doesn't wait around for the answer to be computed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am I incorrect in thinking that the `await Delay..` would only run as a background task since it is inside the lambda?

Answer (score 0):

This appears just to have been user error using the debugger. The debugger is switching to the background task thread and hitting breakpoints there before the response fully returns giving the appearance that control was not being returned to the client and being carried into the background task.

Even after adding some synchronous steps in `QueueBackgroundWorkItemAsync` and putting breakpoints on them, control was not immediately returned to the original http call. Only after I tried adding a long running task like `await Task.Delay(1000);` did enough time/ticks pass for the http response to return. I had conflated this with just the `await` somehow freeing up the original http context.